# Filter an Array in an Observable

Tags: rxjs

Here is an edited sample from learnrxjs. I want to filter the values in the type array. But thats not how it works: 'This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string[]' and 'string' have no overlap.'

I am new to rxjs and cant figure out how to filter the array. Any advices? Is it possible?

```
    const source = from([
         { name: 'Joe', age: 31, type: ['a', 'b'] }, 
         { name: 'Bob', age: 25, type: ['a'] }
    ]);
    //filter out people with type b
    const example = source.pipe(filter(person => person.type != 'a'));
    //output: "People with type b: Bob"
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(`Type a: ${val.name}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `filter()` you are applying takes a function with signature `T => boolean` meaning that you will have to return a boolean true/false so it can filter out elements from the stream.

Your elements `T` are of type `Object {name:string, age:number, type:array}` so to filter on values in the `type` Array you will need to use the [Array.indexOf prototype function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
source.pipe(filter(person => person.type.indexOf('b') == -1) // filter out people who have type b
```